# Get unique values from a column using Python

Tags: python, csv, unique

I'm trying to get unique values from the column 'name' for every distinct value in column 'gender'.

Here's sample data:
sample input_file_data:

```
index,name,gender,alive
1,Adam,Male,Y
2,Bella,Female,N
3,Marc,Male,Y
1,Adam,Male,N
```

I could get it when I give a value corresponding to 'gender' like for example,  gave "Male" in the code below:

```
filtered_data = filter(lambda person: person["gender"] == "Male", input_file_data)
reader = (dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in filtered_data)
countt = [rec[gender] for rec in reader]
final1 = input_file_name + ".txt", "gender", "Male"
output1 = str(final1).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("'","").replace(", [{", " -- [").replace("}", "")
final2 = set(re.findall(r"name': '(.*?)'", str(filtered_data)))
final_count = len(final2)
output = str(final_count) + " occurrences", str(final2)
output2 = output1, str(output)
output_final = str(output2).replace('\\', "").replace('"',"").replace(']"', "]").replace("set", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("'","").replace(", [{", " -- [").replace("}", "")
output_final = output_final + "\n"
```

current output:

```
input_file_name.txt, gender, Male, 2 occurrences, [Adam,Marc]
```

Expected output:

```
input_file_name.txt, gender, Male, 2 occurrences, [Adam,Marc], Female, 1 occurrences [Bella]
```

which should show up all the unique occurrences of names, for every distinct gender value (without hardcoding). Also I do not want to use Pandas. Any help is highly appreciated.

PS- I have multiple files and not all files have the same columns. So I can't hardcode them. Also, all the files have a 'name' column, but not all files have a 'gender' column. And this script should work for any other column like 'index' or 'alive' or anything else for that matter and not just gender.

Comment: why do you not want to use pandas? it is designed for exactly this sort of thing. it's got a bit of a learning curve, but it is abs worth learning.

Comment: @acushner There are a couple more people who will be running this script. They are even more new to Python than I am and installing packages itself is new to them. So I prefer sticking to the packages that are installed on default, if that makes any sense.

Comment: that makes some sense. but to do what you want in pandas it's basically: `df = pd.read_csv(csvfile); print df[df.gender == 'Male']; print df[df.gender == 'Female']`. which seems overall easier. but either way works.

Comment: also, one other thing. maybe consider using anaconda. it has pandas and other great tools by default. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/ (it's free)

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `csv` module along with the `defaultdict` from `collections` for this.  Say this is stored in a file called test.csv:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> with open('test.csv', 'rb') as fin: data = list(csv.reader(fin))[1:]
>>> gender_dict = defaultdict(set)
>>> for idx, name, gender, alive in data:
    gender_dict[gender].add(name)

>>> gender_dict
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'Male': ['Adam', 'Marc'], 'Female': ['Bella']})
```

You now have a dictionary.  Each key is a unique value from the gender column.  Each value is a set, so you'll only get unique items.  Notice that we added `'Adam'` twice, but only see one in the resulting set.

You don't need `defaultdict`, but it allows you to use less boilerplate code to check if a key exists.

EDIT:  It might help to have better visibility into the data itself.  Given your code, I can make the following assumptions:

- `input_file_data` is an iterable (list, tuple, something like that) containing dictionaries.
- Each dictionary contains a `'gender'` key.  If it didn't include at least `'gender'`, you would get a key error when trying to filter it.
- Each dictionary has a `'name'` key, it looks like.

Rather than doing all of that regex, what about this?

```
>>> gender_dict = {'Male': set(), 'Female': set()}
>>> for item in input_file_data:
        gender_dict[item['gender']].add(item['name'])
```

You can use `item.get('name')` instead of `item['name']` if not every entry will have a name.

Edit #2: Ok, the first thing you need to do is get your data into a consistent state.  We can absolutely get to a point where you have a column name (gender, index, alive, whatever you want) and a set of unique names corresponding to those columns.  Something like this:

```
data_dict = {'gender':
                 {'Male': ['Adam', 'Marc'],
                  'Female': ['Bella']}
             'alive':
                 {'Y': ['Adam', 'Marc'],
                  'N': ['Bella', 'Adam']}
             'index':
                 {1: ['Adam'],
                  2: ['Bella'],
                  3: ['Marc']}
              }
```

If that's what you want, you could try this:

```
>>> data_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set)))
>>> for element in input_file_data:
        for key, value in element.items():
            if key != 'name':
                data_dict[key][value].add(element[name])
```

That *should* get you what you want, I think?  I can't test as I don't have your data, but give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My bad. I forgot to mention that I have multiple files and not all files have the same header names. So I can't hardcode them.

Comment: Regardless of the header names, if the columns are at least in the same order you're fine.  I don't directly refer to any headers.  The `idx, name, gender, alive in data` just unpacks each line from the CSV and assigns a value to each of the names.  It doesn't matter what the actual column name is.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case also. The files can be very different. :( I have a couple of more functions in the script currently and it returns an empty file if there's no file with a given header name.

Comment: I've amended my answer a bit.  Let me know if my assumptions are incorrect.  If `input_file_data` has no consistent state, I would concentrate on fixing that before moving on to working on the data itself.

Comment: Yes. there is no consistent state. Apart from that, all the files have a 'name' column, but not all files have a 'gender' column. And this script should not focus just on gender, but should work for any other column like 'index' or 'alive' or anything else for that matter. I'm sorry, but is it doable?

Comment: It's doable, I think, but you need to make some decisions about how the data should be stored.  Rather than worrying about presentation, you need to figure out how to massage this inconsistent data into a logical structure.  I'll see if I can give an example.

Comment: Check out my second edit.  Hopefully that gives you a way forward.  How you display that information is up to you, of course, but you should be able to take your data and get it into something reasonable.